# How to write select query in SQL from excel sheet (name of sheet is in Russian)?

Tags: sql, excel

select user from [Таблица 1$]?
How to write in if is in Russian?
[image]

Comment: Excel doesn't support SQL (at least, not directly), so why are you asking? The only place you need to use Excel sheet names is in Excel's own formula syntax or VBA.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that JET and ACE both support a limited subset of SQL-92 queries against Excel workbooks - is that what you're doing? If so, then using square-brackets should work. e.g. `SELECT user FROM [Таблица 1]` should work. There's no `$` in there at all though.

Comment: What error you get? Do you use dynamic SQL - then you need to write query in unicode.

Comment: I just need to write a sample of query, if the sheet name was in English I suppose I will write FROM [Sheet1$], so in different language the syntax is the same right?